# Any way of creating an Client Certificate programmatically for SSL Client-Auth without BouncyCastle?

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, x509, authentication

I'm writing a server application that identifies it's clients by SSL-Client-Auth. Every Client should create it's own KeyPair and Certificate to connect to this server. Any unknown client (identified by a new public key) will be thread as a new client and registered with this public key. I don't want to sign client certs serverside (since this is would not increase security).

But it seems (after studing hundreds of pages) that I can't create the necessary files (or objects) programatically in plain Java, since the KeyStore would need at least self-signed client-certificates (which I can't create without BouncyCastle lib).

Am i wrong or is there really no way to do this?

And please provide me with a link or code. Java SSL semms to be VERY overcomplicated and has a bad documentation.

Comment: If you want to use the JSSE API in a way it's not normally used, you're bound to end up in obscure corners of the API and its documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is nothing in the JSSE API (including JSSE and JCE) to issue an X.509 certificate indeed. Dealing with the X.509 structures manually is actually quite complex, and you'd certainly need to read a lot more if you want to replicate what BouncyCastle does, without using BouncyCastle.

BouncyCastle is by far the most convenient way to achieve what you want. You could also use the `sun.*` packages (since `keytool` uses them to produce self-signed certificates), but using these packages is usually bad practice, since they're not part of the public JSSE API. They are not documented, rely on a specific implementation of the JSSE, and are subject to change. In contrast, BouncyCastle is meant to be used as a library.

> I don't want to sign client certs serverside (since this is would not
>   increase security).

Since your server will only use the public key (and not the certificate) to perform the authentication (based on whatever mapping between public key and user you choose to implement), issuing the certificate on the server side or the client side doesn't matter in terms of security. The client could self-sign anything it wants, to the server can only rely on the public key anyway, not the rest of the certificate. The reason you'd need to "bundle" the public key into an X.509 certificate is because it's the only kind of client certificate supported (for example, the JSSE doesn't support OpenPGP certificates).

Having a service on your server that receives a public key and sends an X.509 certificate (with any dummy attributes, signed by any private key) might be the easiest option. In addition, if you use a mini CA internal to that server, this would simplify the way you'd need to tweak the trust managers to get the self-signed certificates through. (You'd still need to check the actual public key with your internal mapping, if you want to design such a security scheme.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I'm running this code on Android I don't even have the sun.* classes. But creating the client certificates on the server is a nice idea. I will try this. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see, BouncyCastle on Android seems to be problematic anyway. You could also try [SpongyCastle](http://rtyley.github.com/spongycastle/).